# JavaMail with gmail SMTP - How to handle an unexisting email addresses

Tags: spring-boot, jakarta-mail

In my project I'm using a JavaMail implementation to send emails through GMAIL's SMTP server. 
The general concept is ok, my custom validators checks whether the e-mail was correctly formulated etc...

Everything is fine, however I am not able to catch anything what should be considered, as unsent email. I went deeper into JavaMail docs, and they advised to catch SendMailException and MessageException, but based on the code, it handles only an incorrectly formulated e-mail addresses or an empty Strings. If the user will come up with an unexisting email, but well formulated, the API will not inform that anything happened.

Did anyone handle with the similar issue and knows how to go forward? 
Thanks in advance for your help.

```
@Bean
public JavaMailSender javaMailSender(EmailProperties prop) {
    JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    mailSender.setHost(prop.getHost());
    mailSender.setPort(prop.getPort());
    mailSender.setUsername(prop.getUsername());
    mailSender.setPassword(prop.getPassword());
    mailSender.setDefaultFileTypeMap(FileTypeMap.getDefaultFileTypeMap());
    mailSender.setJavaMailProperties(getProperties(prop));
    mailSender.setProtocol(prop.getProtocol());
    mailSender.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return mailSender;
}

private Properties getProperties(EmailProperties prop) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", prop.getProtocol());
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", prop.getAuth());
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", prop.getStarttls());
    props.put("mail.debug", prop.getDebug());
    return props;
}
```

Comment: I think still you will get an error for this `If the user will come up with an unexisting email,` have you tried ?

Comment: Hi Deadpool, 
Yes, if the email is not existing, but is formulated correctly, then the situation will remain the same. The gmail will return the Undelivered message, but in Java no response at all.

Comment: See the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#badaddr).